# SQLite: Howto Insert Foreign Key Values Into A Cross Reference Table

Tags: sql, sqlite

Given the following data table definitions in SQLite Version 3.7.5:

```
CREATE TABLE [Books] (
  [Title] VARCHAR(125) NOT NULL, 
  [YearPublished] INT, 
  CONSTRAINT [CK_YearPublished] CHECK(YearPublished >= 1400));

CREATE TABLE [People] (
  [FirstName] VARCHAR(25) NOT NULL, 
  [LastName] VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL, 
  [MiddleName] VARCHAR(25), 
  CONSTRAINT [UQ_PersonName] UNIQUE([FirstName], [LastName], [MiddleName]));

CREATE TABLE [BooksAuthorsXRef] (
  [BookID] INT NOT NULL CONSTRAINT [FK_BookID] REFERENCES [Books]([rowid]), 
  [PersonID] INT NOT NULL CONSTRAINT [FK_PersonID] REFERENCES [People]([rowid]));
```

What SQL command can I use to populate the BookID and PersonID field values in the BooksAuthorsXRef data table to use the values for the rowid for a specific Title in the Books table to be associated with the rowid in the Persons table for a given LastName, FirstName, and MiddleName set of values?

I've already populated the Books table with one record;

```
INSERT INTO
       Books       
VALUES
      ('Stingray Shuffle', 2003);
```

And, the Persons table has been populated with the following record:

```
INSERT INTO 
       People
       (LastName, FirstName)       
VALUES
       ('Dorsey', 'Tim')
```

What SQL command would I use in SQLite to define that Tim Dorsey (Persons rowid = 1) is the author of the book entitled "Stingray Shuffle" in the Books table (Books rowid = 1)?

Also, based on the data table definitions, are any changes needed to make adding and changing Books and Persons cross reference records in the BooksAuthorsXRef data table more managable and easier while maintaining some degree of referential integrity?

Thank you in advance for your time, help and patience.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you've an existing table with all of the book + person data in it, you can do the following:

```
INSERT INTO BooksAuthorsXRef
SELECT      B.[rowid], P.[rowid]
FROM        XRefTemp T
INNER JOIN  Books B
ON          B.Title = T.Title
INNER JOIN  People P
ON          P.FirstName = T.FirstName
AND         COALESCE(P.MiddleName, '') = COALESCE(T.MiddleName, '')
AND         P.LastName = T.LastName
```

When inserting individual records, the [last_insert_rowid()](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_corefunc.html#last_insert_rowid) function will give you the rowid for the Book / People record you've just inserted.

To insert a record for an existing Book / Person, use:

```
INSERT INTO BooksAuthorsXRef
SELECT      B.[rowid], P.[rowid]
FROM        Books B
INNER JOIN  People P
ON          P.FirstName = 'TheFirstName'
AND         COALESCE(P.MiddleName, '') = 'TheMiddleName or empty if none'
AND         P.LastName = 'TheLastName'
WHERE       B.Title = 'TheBookTitle'
```

Comment: Thank you, Will. Am I following you correctly that I have to have a third data table, either temporary or physical, in the database named XRefTemp that contains all of the columns from both the existing Books and Persons data tables in order to insert new records into BooksAuthorsXRef?  And, that as I add a new Book and, if needed, Person record to each respective table, that I would also need to insert a cross reference record into the XRefTemp table before I can update the BooksAuthorsXRef?

Comment: Is there a way to insert a record into BooksAuthorsXRef without using a separate temporary or physical database table, supposing that I know the Title of the Book and the LastName and FirstName of the author (Person)?

Comment: @ClockEndGooner - yes, for a bulk load ideally you'd have a table as you've described as anything else won't allow you to perform lookups into the Books / People table.  If you know the title of an existing Books record and the First + Middle + Last names of a Person, you just need to use the second query I've included above.

Comment: Spot on Will; the second SQL statement for inserting a new row into the BooksAuthorsXRef database table worked as expected. I did notice one thing with the third party Windows application I was using; Performing the "INSERT INTO" as written above caused an error message of "Foreign Key Mismatch", whereas the SQLite Command Line for sqlite3.exe Version 3.7.6.3 worked without issue.  Looks like I may have a bug to submit to the third party developer to review.  

Again Will, many thanks for your time, help and patience.

Comment: No problem, CEG - always a pleasure to assist.  Am in the dark re: the Foreign Key Mismatch I'm afraid - could well be a bug!

Comment: The foreign key mismatch was an issue I came across using SQLite Expert Professional.  By default, foreign_keys constraints in sqlite3.exe enforcement of foreign key constraints are disabled, where SQLite Expert has foreign_keys enforcement enabled by default.  When foreign_keys was set to on in SQLite Expert, I could not execute the second INSERT INTO command for directly updating the BooksAuthorsXRef database table; with foreign_keys off, I could directly insert records into BooksAuthorsXRef table.

Comment: From what I've read elsewhere, namely http://nitoprograms.blogspot.com/2010/06/sqlite-and-entity-framework-4.html, once I have a set of sample data values complete, and then want to update the same tables correctly using Microsoft Entity Framework 4.0, I'll need to enforce foreign key constraints.